# Dump Json response to a bash variable

Tags: json, bash, curl, jq

I have the following ouput

```
[
 "notimportant",
     [
       "val1",
       "val2",
       ...,
       "valn"
     ]
]
```

I'm trying to store every value into a bash string, using jq I tried this

```
out=''
req=$(curl -s $url)
len=$(echo $req | jq length ) 
for (( i = 0; i < $len; i++ )); do
    element=$(echo $req | jq '.[1]' | jq --argjson i "$i" '.[$i]')
    out=${element}\n${out}
done
```

which feels clunky and also has a slow performance. I'm trying to dump the values at once without looping on all the elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an array:

```
mapfile -t arr < <(curl -s "$url" | jq -r '.[1] | .[]')
declare -p arr
```

Comment: It may be better to delimit records by a `null` rather than `newline` to be compatible with JSON strings containing newline characters: `mapfile -d '' arr < <(curl -s "$url"  | a.json jq -j '.[1] | .[]+"\u0000"')`

Answer (score 2):

Do you want the values separate by TAB or NEWLINE characters in a single variable?  The `@tsv` function is [useful for controlling output](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Builtinoperatorsandfunctions):

```
outTABS=$(curl -s "$url" | jq -r '.[1]|.|@tsv')
outLINE=$(curl -s "$url" | jq -r '.[1]|.[]|[.]|@tsv')

> echo "$outTABS"
val1    val2    valn

> echo "$outLINE"
val1
val2
valn
```